# How to access class methods from anonymous suspend function inside constructor in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I want to be able to call functions from the anonymous constructor's suspend function in the following example:

```
data class SuspendableStep(
    val condition: SuspendableCondition, 
    val continuation: Continuation<Unit>
)
```

```
class WaitCondition(cycles: Int) : SuspendableCondition() {

    private val timer = SomeTimer(cycles)

    override fun resume(): Boolean = timer.elapsed() // timer is handled somewhere else

    override fun toString(): String = "WaitCondition_$timer"
}
```

```
class BasicContinuation : Continuation<Unit> {

    var coroutine: Continuation<Unit>
    override val context: CoroutineContext = EmptyCoroutineContext
    private var nextStep: SuspendableStep? = null

    constructor(task: suspend () -> Unit) {
        coroutine = task.createCoroutine(completion = this)
    }

    override fun resumeWith(result: Result<Unit>) {
        nextStep = null
        result.exceptionOrNull()?.let { e -> Logger.handle("Error with plugin!", e) }
    }

    suspend fun wait(cycles: Int): Unit = suspendCoroutine {
        check(cycles > 0) { "Wait cycles must be greater than 0." }
        nextStep = SuspendableStep(WaitCondition(cycles), it)
    }

}
```

```
fun main() {
    BasicContinuation({
        println("HELLO")
        wait(1)
        println("WORLD")
    }).coroutine.resume(Unit)
}
```

There only other option I found was to override a suspend function by creating an anonymous inner class and calling another function to set the coroutine:

```
fun main() {
    val bc = BasicContinuation() {
        override suspend fun test() : Unit {
            println("HELLO")
            wait(1)
            println("WORLD")   
        }
    }
    bc.set() // assign coroutine to suspend { test }.createCoroutine(completion = this)
    bc.coroutine.resume(Unit)
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to re-implement coroutines on top of coroutines? Seems like a really strange stuff.

Comment: No, I just want to be able to access shortcut utility methods that I will reuse more than once to suspend the coroutine.

Comment: Well, I don't know your specific case and I'm aware my question is kind of off topic here. But wouldn't it be enough to create your util as a regular suspend function? For example: `suspend fun wait(cycles: Int)`. Then you can use it as any other suspend function, without any continuation voodoo.

Comment: I need coroutines to be able to pause the execution of the active tasks. The suspend wait function wouldn't work since you have to define inside it how long you want to wait. I want to be able to calculate it myself using game ticks (ticks are not always the same length depending on alot of factors). Plus, you would have to declare it in every class you want to use it since you can't access it in BasicContinuation without the CoroutineScope I added in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used CoroutineScope to extend the scope of the functions I could access:

```
class BasicContinuation : Continuation<Unit> {

    var coroutine: Continuation<Unit>
    override val context: CoroutineContext = EmptyCoroutineContext
    private var nextStep: SuspendableStep? = null

    constructor(task: (suspend BasicContinuation.(CoroutineScope) -> Unit)) {
        coroutine = suspend { task.invoke(this, CoroutineScope(context)) }.createCoroutine(completion = this)
    }

    override fun resumeWith(result: Result<Unit>) {
        nextStep = null
        result.exceptionOrNull()?.let { e -> Logger.handle("Error with plugin!", e) }
    }

    suspend fun wait(cycles: Int): Unit = suspendCoroutine {
        check(cycles > 0) { "Wait cycles must be greater than 0." }
        nextStep = SuspendableStep(WaitCondition(cycles), it)
    }

}
```

```
fun main() {
    val bc = BasicContinuation({
        println("Hello")
        wait(1)
        println("World")
    })
    bc.coroutine.resume(Unit) // print "Hello"
    // increment timer
    bc.coroutine.resume(Unit) // print "World
}
```